# wp_editor removes HTML and inline styles

Tags: front-end, editor, wp-editor

I use the `wp_editor` function to display an editor in front-end.

The problem is that this editor doesnt behave like the editor in backend based on the settings I give as input:

```
$settings = array(
        'wpautop' => true,
            'media_buttons' => false,
        'tinymce' => array(
                'theme_advanced_buttons1' =>                       'formatselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,' .
                                'bullist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter' .
                                ',justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|' .
                                ',spellchecker,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv ',
                                                                'mode' => 'specific_textareas',
),
'quicktags' => false);

wp_editor($content, 'contentEditorBox', $settings );
```

The website is a front end private community, and the content inserted by all members is coming from Microsoft Word. This same content, if instered in backend, appear as a text wrapped by HTML tags (`p`, `br`...) and inline CSS styles when I swap to HTML mode in editor. But in front end, the editor doesn't show the mode tabs, and content is always raw content containing no HTML and no styles.

I need that the content maintain its style i.e, to be inserted from front end like it does from backend.

How can copy-paste from MS word to wordpress editor in front end maintain the styles and HTML?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was coming from a php function strip_tags, that was in my code without observing it. I removed it and the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You must filter the content inside the editor, if you save the content. Alternativly add a tiny button to add content from MS Word inside the editor area.

I think for the usability is it better, if you filter the content from users on save his content. You can use the project [WordOff](https://github.com/tomdyson/wordoff) to filter the content from MS Word and create clean html.

Alternative filter helpers:

- [Regex Solution](http://tim.mackey.ie/CleanWordHTMLUsingRegularExpressions.aspx)
- [Console Tool](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/cleaning-words-nasty-html.html)

Comment: Your answer contains many information new to me, I will understand it. Thank you very much for your time and explanations.

Comment: I need that the content is insterted with HTML tags and inline styles, I dont need to create clean HTML but maintain the original HTML, as it comes from MS Word.